# Chart.js 2.0.0-beta2 disable points on line Charts

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to disable point display on 2.0.0-beta2 line type charts?

How?

I have a weekly graph with time scale where data is hourly. All works well but there are too many points. I would prefer a graph with just lines and without points. I searched the documentation but I haven't seen any option about it.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a bit late but still.
I had this same issue & searched the Source code for this (Because It used to be: pointDot: false which isn't working anymore)

There are 2 ways of doing this now:

1. Use the options (This is in the documentation [nnick.github Chartjs](http://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/#line-chart) & Search for point.radius)

   options: { 
               elements: { point: { radius: 1,  hitRadius: 1, hoverRadius: 4 } } 
           }
2. Use the property from the line dataset itself

   ```
       data: {                
           datasets: [{
               radius: 0,
   ```

Small remark: when using radius: 0 it's hard to find the point when mouseover

Comment: Not sure why, the docs @ http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-example-usage tell me it should be "pointRadius." I believe the documentation is already dated.